# How are "Problem Complexity" and "Solution Complexity" different?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

I am in an algorithms course, and my professor keeps specifying "we are talking about *Problem* complexity here, not *Solution* complexity". I would like to gain an intuitive understanding of the difference between these two. Do you all have an example(s) that can help me to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem complexity is the best we can achieve for a given problem (sometimes under given restrictions). We usually talk about problem complexity when dealing with lower-bounds and it means there is probably no algorithm with lower time/place complexity than the proved ones.

Algorithm complexity is on the other hand the resources needed for a specific algorithm to run. When some algorithm solves a given problem in time $t$, we know that this problem has at most time complexity $t$ and hence, the complexity of an algorithm is an upper-bound for the complexity of the problem it solves.

Comment: This is very clear, thanks. "An algorithm is an upper-bound bound for the complexity of the problem it solves" wrapped it all together for me.